# qpbo library doesn't compile

Tags: c++, image-processing, computer-vision

I am trying to compile a QPBO library. The library, I am downloading from: http://pub.ist.ac.at/~vnk/software.html

I am testing with the example given in QPBO.h.

This is my CMakelists.txt(I don't think anything wrong is here, but...)

```
project(qpbo_test)

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

include_directories(./)

file(GLOB allsrc "QPBO_extra.cpp" "QPBO_maxflow.cpp" "QPBO_postprocessing.cpp" "QPBO.cpp")

add_library(CommonLib ${allsrc})

add_executable(qpbo main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(qpbo CommonLib)
```

When I do cmake . and make, I get the following error:

> ld: 216 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64

I think the problem is that I didn't use the template initialization file instances.inc but how to use it?

Comment: Have you tried contacting prof. Kolmogorov?

Comment: What platform are you compiling this on?

Comment: I am compiling on Macos Lion. I didn't try to contact Kolmogorov. Someone helped me out by changing the template .cpp model to .h model(Sorry, I don't know the exact C++ terms in english). So I think it is just that my compiler doesn't support template .cpp model.

Comment: Hardly an answer to your question, but my 10 cents is to have a look at the [OpenGM](http://hci.iwr.uni-heidelberg.de/opengm2/) library which is a well maintained library for GM algorithms such as QPBO (including wrappers for the original author implementations).